# How do i print a line with input using a line/2 predicate in prolog

Tags: prolog

ive came this far. im new to prolog and i want to make simple figures. i want to make the input like this:

```
line(X,Y):-
read(Y), print(Y).
print(Y) :- write(Y).

this should be the result.

?- line(8, X).
XXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I've understood your question properly but how about:

```
line(Length,Char) :-
    length(List,Length),
    maplist(=(Char),List),
    atomic_list_concat(List,Atom),
    write(Atom).
```

So `line(8,'X')` would print `XXXXXXXX` and `line(3,q)` would print `qqq`.

Uses:

- [length/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=length/2)
- [maplist/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=maplist/2)
- [atomic_list_concat/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atomic_list_concat/2)

Comment: `atom_chars(Atom, List)` in place of `atomic_list_concat(List,Atom)` suffices.

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything in your code to count down on the `X` argument that your pass to `line` predicate.

Try this code:

```
line(X,Y):-
    read(Y),
    print(X,Y).
    
print(0,_).
print(X,Y) :-
    X>0,
    write(Y),
    X2 is X - 1,
    print(X2,Y).
```

When I run that I get this:

```
?- line(8,X).
|: 3.
33333333
X = 3 .
```